# EF Core 3.1 TruncateTime

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Trabajo con EF Core 3.1
Necesito el equivalente de `DbFunctions.TruncateTime` en EF Core 3.1

Código de EF6

```
(filter.HasFechaHasta && DbFunctions.TruncateTime(sc.FechaEmision) <= filter.FechaHasta)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entiendo que en `EF Core`  puede usar el `.Date` del DateTime

```
(filter.HasFechaHasta && sc.FechaEmision.Date <= filter.FechaHasta)
```

para acceder a la fecha sin su hora

[DbFunctions.TruncateTime LINQ equivalent in EF CORE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40758784/dbfunctions-truncatetime-linq-equivalent-in-ef-core)